# show loading dialog for multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making two ajax call asynchronously, on each call I am showing a loading dialog box like this,

```
jQuery('#msg_writter').show();
```

on success of each request I will hide the loading dialog like this,

```
jQuery('#msg_writter').fadeOut(1000);
```

my html code for loading dialog:

```
<div id="msg_writter" class="msgWritter">    
     <img src="/images/loading.gif"/>
</div>
```

when the first request is done, the loading dialog gets disappear so loading dialog is not showing for the second request.

How could I modify the code to show the loading dialog from the first request till the success of last request.

Comment: show your ajax call code

Comment: I show the loading dialog two time first on by default of html itself and second from a ajax request from a javascript file, this request will called before document ready function. I hide the loading dialog two time, first on document ready function and second on ajax request success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must count AJAX request counts:

```
var activeAjaxCount = 0;

// When making request, increment count and show loader
activeAjaxCount++;
jQuery('#msg_writter').show();

// On complete callback, decrease count and fadeout loader if count is zero
activeAjaxCount--;
if (activeAjaxCount == 0) {
    jQuery('#msg_writter').fadeOut(1000);
}
```

You can also use [$.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [$.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to solve that globally.

```
var activeAjaxCount = 0;

$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    activeAjaxCount++;
    $('#msg_writter').show();
});

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    activeAjaxCount--;
    if (activeAjaxCount == 0) {
        jQuery('#msg_writter').fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The documentation says for ajaxStart that "Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins. This is an Ajax Event.". My guess is that for this example you'd better make use of ajaxSend: "Attach a function to be executed before an Ajax request is sent. This is an Ajax Event."

Answer (score 2):

Use [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
jQuery('#msg_writter').show();
var a = $.ajax(...);
var b = $.ajax(...); // the other call
$.when(a,b).always(function() {
    jQuery('#msg_writter').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: This really is the nicest way to go, deferred execution and promises is so much cleaner then having counters or other values that try to keep track of state.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var test1 = false;
var test2 = false;

var onSuccessAjax1 = function () {
    test1 = true;
    if (test1 && test2) {
        //hide loading animation
    }
}

var onSuccessAjax2 = function () {
    test2 = true;
    if (test1 && test2) {
        //hide loading animation
    }
}
```

you have to call the onSuccessAjax functions when your ajax call terminate with success

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a very old question
but i didn't find any simple and effective solution anywhere so i searched more and found out that jquery provides `.ajaxStop()`
function specifically for this purpose
here's the link of the documentation
https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/